# Is there a way to tell why a Cloud DataStore transaction failed?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I'm using the Ruby client, and only see 
`` Google::Cloud::Datastore::TransactionError: Transaction failed to commit.
from /myapp/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/google-cloud-datastore-1.4.4/lib/google/cloud/datastore/dataset.rb:555:in `rescue in transaction' ``

Is there a verbosity setting or something where I can see more trace?

Comment: Was anything written to the Stackdriver logs?

Comment: Donno if useful, but from what I observed with the python ndb library is that the reason is sometimes mentioned, apparently when it's not the "usual" (i.e. transaction conflict) one. For example the "too much contention" one shows up (sometimes even showing the entity in question).

Comment: My particular issue was an error in my code - but as far as I can tell there isn't a way to differentiate between that and some transient issue. I suspect I have another issue related to an entity not existing when I query but I can't tell from the trace. No Stackdriver logs that I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

> there isn't a way to differentiate between that and some transient issue

Yes, it's a flaw in SDK. They eat your original exception. Read about it in my ticket thread:

https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-ruby/pull/2033